# Failing SQL insert

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I wonder if someone could help me with this SQL insert query?   I've a nasty suspicion that I am staring at something very obvious, but I've been trying to figure it out for a while now, and I can't see what's wrong.  At the moment it just drops through to the catch loop when I try and execute.   I'm using Visual studio Community 2015.   Incidentally, is there anywhere in VS where you can try out a SQL statement?

Here's the code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
            myConnection.Open();
            if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
            }

            SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            myCommand3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dbo.Values (Portfolio Name,Date,Daily Value,Daily Percent) VALUES ('Ascentric',@SQLTime,2000,0.01)";
            //myCommand.Parameters.Add("@SQLPortName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            //myCommand.Parameters["@SQLPortName"].Value = "Eric";
            myCommand3.Parameters.Add("@SQLTime", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime );
            myCommand3.Parameters["@SQLTime"].Value = DateTime.Today;
            myCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nope.  Didn't work");
        }



    }
```

And here's the table:

[image]

By the way, I do understand that I need to parameterise this, but I am just trying to get the basic statement to work at the moment.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: For future reference, include the specific error message in your post, and when it comes to debugging SQL, look at the `SqlCommand.CommandText` property, copy the value and try executing it directly in SQL Server Management Studio to make sure it's actually valid SQL. Also, don't just do `catch { }`-- instead, determine the actual types of `Exception` that can be thrown by the code in your `try` block, catch those and look at what the `Message` is. Ex `catch (SqlException sqlEx) { MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message); }`

Comment: The `Exception` in your catch would likely have displayed some helpful information about the malformed SQL. Since this is SQL Server, you probably also have SQL Server Profiler installed. This is a very handy tool that allows you to capture the SQL statements that have been sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to wrap your column names in brackets if they include spaces, or are a reserved keyword (such as Date):

```
 myCommand3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dbo.Values ([Portfolio Name],[Date],[Daily Value],[Daily Percent]) VALUES ('Ascentric',@SQLTime,2000,0.01)";
```

As a best practice: Don't *ever* use spaces in SQL for objects (columns, SPROCS, etc). Use CamelCase or underscores_to_separate_words. Because you'll forget the brackets again one day.

Comment: The real answer here is, "Don't put spaces in your column names"

Answer (score 2):

Creating columns with Space is not the best practice to follow. First remove spaces and make your columns as single word. If you want to show spaces at the time of selection you may use alias instead.

```
myCommand3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Values (PortfolioName,[Date],DailyValue,DailyPercent) VALUES ('Ascentric',@SQLTime,2000,0.01)";
myCommand3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SQLTime",DateTime.Today.ToString());
```

Comment: While I too prefer camel case column names, at the very least use an underscore instead of a space if you *have* to have some sort of spacing character between the words.

Comment: Got it.  Don't do spaces!.   Thanks for that and the other points.